# Step Into Fails and Breakpoints Not Hit in Visual Studio 2017 C# Project

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 is ignoring the breakpoint in my project.  It refuses to step into the code and displays a message "cannot step into non-user code".  This is a single project C# solution for WinForms using no third party components.  I went to Debugging options to uncheck "Enable for Just My Code" to no avail.  When opening the Debugging > Modules window I see this:

[image]

I am using the Debug Config.  Clean and rebuild, restarting Visual Studio doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  My method returned an IEnumerable<> generic which was not processed yet although I was checking the count through String interpolation $"{listVar.Count}".  Once I actually tried to enumerate the collection, the breakpoint was hit.

Still strange that the User Code in Modules reads N/A.  From what I've read, this should be a "Yes" or a "No"

Comment: This behavior(the N/A) is by design I think. I tried in VS2015,VS2017 and VS2019, if we debug with `Just my code` option disabled in even a console app, the moudles window will display N/A. In my opinion, it seems that the debugger won't try to determine if the loaded symbol come from user code or not since we've disabled `Enable just my code`. So you don't need to worry about that, it's normal behavior. And thanks for your sharing, you can consider marking it as answer:)